# Optical quantum computers VS Superconducting quantum computers VS Electron-spin quantum computers

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices, superconducting-quantum-computing, photonics, spintronics

One of the main problems of superconducting quantum computers is that it is necessary to maintain a very low temperature (near absolute zero).
Such cooling is very expensive and complex.

[image: cool]

Why, then, are Intel, IBM, and many other corporations developing superconducting quantum computers? After all, it was possible to use a photon as a qubit.

And what about electron-spin quantum computers?
Are there any corporations that have advanced in their development? Do they require cooling to absolute zero?

In most of the materials that I came across, it was said about spin of the electron. But using it in the real world is somehow unpopular. Perhaps there are reasons for this?

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of developing superconducting quantum computers, optical quantum computers and electron-spin quantum computers.